# TFLearn model evaluation

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, tflearn

I am new to the machine learning and TensorFlow. I am trying to train a simple model to recognize gender. I use small data-set of height, weight, and shoe size. However, I have encountered a problem with evaluating model's accuracy.
Here's the entire code:

```
import tflearn
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# [height, weight, shoe_size]
X = [[181, 80, 44], [177, 70, 43], [160, 60, 38], [154, 54, 37], [166, 65, 40],
     [190, 90, 47], [175, 64, 39], [177, 70, 40], [159, 55, 37], [171, 75, 42],
     [181, 85, 43], [170, 52, 39]]

# 0 - for female, 1 - for male
Y = [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]

data = np.column_stack((X, Y))
np.random.shuffle(data)

# Split into train and test set
X_train, Y_train = data[:8, :3], data[:8, 3:]
X_test, Y_test = data[8:, :3], data[8:, 3:]

# Build neural network
net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 3])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 32)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 32)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 1, activation='linear')
net = tflearn.regression(net, loss='mean_square')

# fix for tflearn with TensorFlow 12:
col = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES)
for x in col:
    tf.add_to_collection(tf.GraphKeys.VARIABLES, x)

# Define model
model = tflearn.DNN(net)
# Start training (apply gradient descent algorithm)
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, n_epoch=100, show_metric=True)

score = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test)
print('Training test score', score)

test_male = [176, 78, 42]
test_female = [170, 52, 38]
print('Test male: ', model.predict([test_male])[0])
print('Test female:', model.predict([test_female])[0])
```

Even though model's prediction is not very accurate

```
Test male:  [0.7158362865447998]
Test female: [0.4076206684112549]
```

The `model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test)` always returns `1.0`. How do I calculate real accuracy on the test data-set using TFLearn?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to do binary classification in this case. Your network is set to perform linear regression.

First, transform the labels (gender) to categorical features:

```
from tflearn.data_utils import to_categorical
Y_train = to_categorical(Y_train, nb_classes=2)
Y_test = to_categorical(Y_test, nb_classes=2)
```

The output layer of your network needs two output units for the two classes you want to predict. Also the activation needs to be softmax for classification. The tf.learn default loss is cross-entropy and the default metric is accuracy, so this is already correct.

```
# Build neural network
net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 3])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 32)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 32)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 2, activation='softmax')
net = tflearn.regression(net)
```

The output will now be a vector with the probability for each gender. For example:

```
[0.991, 0.009] #female
```

Bear in mind that you will hopelessly overfit the network with your tiny data set. This means that during training the accuracy will approach 1 while, the accuracy on your test set will be quite poor.

Comment: Thanks, for the great input. I have one doubt that to_categorical() our Y_train is looking something like this :
[[ 1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.]]

Comment: Why the output has to be two neurons instead of one for a binary classification task?